# Clip raster without changing cell alignment and avoid resampling on ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, arcgis-10.4, raster-conversion

I trying to clip a raster (either by Clip or Extract by Mask) with a polygon.
The original input raster is not aligned to the north but it is aligned to the satellite track.

I have two question:

1. How do I clip the input raster using a polygon without changing the cell alignment?
2. How do I clip the input raster using a polygon without resampling the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Clip Tool ([Docs](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm)).

Specifically both of your questions are answered by leaving the `Maintain Clipping Extent` box unchecked:

[image: maintain clipping extent checkbox]

This is explained in the help bar if you're using the tool in arcMap. It is a little confusing because the extent you maintain is that of the clipping layer not the raster layer.

[image: maintain clipping extent Docs]

Finally since you want the raster clipped to the edge of the polygon make sure you check `Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry (optional)`.

Comment: Thanks, actually i'm fully aware of it and tried it so many time but i keep getting the clipped raster aligned horizontally to north and no to the satellite track as in the input raster.

Comment: In that case edit your question to describe (or post a screen shot) of what you've tried so it's not repeated back to you. if you could share a sample of the raster and polygon your trying to clip it with that would also be helpful. Finally if you have access to other tools - e.g. envi, gdal or orfeo -then list those as well.